# Build IQueryable.Any with Expression Trees for LINQ queries

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I'm building a SQL "WHERE" clause dynamically using the System.Linq.Expressions.Expression class. It works well for simple clauses, e.g. to add "PhaseCode = X" clause, I do the following:

```
var equalTarget = Expression.Constant(phaseCode, typeof(int?));
var phaseEquals = Expression.Equal(Expression.PropertyOrField(projParam, "PhaseCode"), equalTarget);
```

However, now I'm trying to build an expression that will return the record if a project has been assigned to a particular group. Project and Group has many-to-many relationship.
Without the expression trees, I would do it as follows:

```
db.Projects.Where(p => .... && p.GroupsAssigned.Any(g => g.ID == groupId))
```

However, I can't seem to find a way to express that with the Expression class.
There are actually two things I can't figure out:

- How to traverse the relationships between tables
- How to do x.Any()

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Calling an extension method, like [Enumerable.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) or [Queryable.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534338.aspx), is simply a static method call on the sequence and the lambda expression you created for the `WHERE` clause. You can use [`Expression.Call`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301084.aspx) to do this:

```
// for Enumerable.Any<T>(IEnumerable<T>,Predicate<T>)
var overload = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods("Any")
                                 .Single(mi => mi.GetParameters().Count() == 2);
var call = Expression.Call(
    overload,
    Expression.PropertyOrField(projParam, "GroupsAssigned"),
    anyLambda);
```

For `Queryable.Any<T>`, you'll need to roll this up into a method:

```
static Expression BuildAny<TSource>(Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
{
    var overload = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods("Any")
                              .Single(mi => mi.GetParameters().Count() == 2);
    var call = Expression.Call(
        overload,
        Expression.PropertyOrField(projParam, "GroupsAssigned"),
        predicate);   

    return call;
}
```

Although this seems odd that you're unable to do this through a normal query.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, sixlettervariables. The Expression.Call() was exactly what I needed. To answer your question, I can't do a normal query in this case because I don't know at compile time how many AND parts in my WHERE statement I will have. It all depends on the selections the user makes in the search form. Constructing the expression tree seems to be the only valid solution.

Comment: Thanks god I saw this, my mistake was I was calling
`typeof(Queryable).GetMethods("Any").Single(mi => mi.GetParameters().Count() == 2);`
Instead of:

`typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods("Any").Single(mi => mi.GetParameters().Count() == 2);`