# How to express All have Any with Expression Trees

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

For a given search tags filter, the expected outcome is an expression representing entities with All tags in a given list of tags ids.

A Lambda might express this as:

```
class Tag 
{
   public long TagId { get; set; }
}

class Taggable 
{
   ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

...

IEnumerable<long> searchTags = new List<long>() { 1, 2, 3 };
Func<Taggable, bool> filter = taggable => searchTags.All(qtag => taggable.Tags.Any(tag => tag.TagId == qtag));
```

An attempt to represent this as an expression tree fails:

```
var tagParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Tag), "tag");    
var taggableParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Taggable), "taggable");
MemberExpression tagsProperty = Expression.Property(taggableParam, "Tags");
ConstantExpression searchTagsConstant = Expression.Constant(searchTags);

var containsCall = Expression.Call(
      typeof(Enumerable), "Contains",
      new[] { typeof(long) },
      searchTagsConstant,
      Expression.Property(tagParam, "TagID")
);

var anyCall = Expression.Call(
     typeof(Enumerable), "Any",
     new[] { typeof(Tag) },
     tagsProperty,
     Expression.Lambda(containsCall, tagParam)
);

// FAILS HERE
var allCall = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Enumerable), "All",
    new[] { typeof(long) },
    searchTagsConstant,
    anyCall
);
```

> No generic method 'All' on type 'System.Linq.Enumerable' is compatible
>   with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments
>   should be provided if the method is non-generic.

It was thought it would work as the `Enumerable.All<TSource, Func<TSource, bool>>` should be satisfied by the `searchTagsConstant` and `anyCall`?

Comment: Look at the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368059/build-iqueryable-any-with-expression-trees-for-linq-queries

Comment: Can you please fix your code example to define what `taggable` is in your line `Expression.Property(taggable, "Tags");`?

Comment: @Stand__Sure That answer is simply for an `Any`. Question is about an All with Any.

Comment: Both are static extensions. The approach should work for both

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> t was thought it would work as the `Enumerable.All<TSource, Func<TSource, bool>>` should be satisfied by the `searchTagsConstant` and `anyCall`

Nope. `anyCall` is not lambda expression (`Func<TSource, bool>`), only a potential *body* of such expression.

Let start from your target:

```
IEnumerable<long> searchTags = new List<long>() { 1, 2, 3 };

Expression<Func<Taggable, bool>> lambda = 
    taggable => searchTags.All(searchTag => taggable.Tags.Any(tag => tag.TagId == searchTag));
```

The easiest way to learn how to build expression tree is to create a sample expression at compile time and examine the generated code via some decompiler or the expression tree at runtime via debugger.

Anyway, note that the above expression has 3 lambda parameters, while in your attempt you have only 2. Also there is no `Contains` call, not sure why you've put in there.

Building the above expression can be like this:

```
var taggable = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Taggable), "taggable");
var tag = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Tag), "tag");
var searchTag = Expression.Parameter(typeof(long), "searchTag");
// tag.TagId == searchTag
var anyCondition = Expression.Equal(
    Expression.Property(tag, "TagId"),
    searchTag);
// taggable.Tags.Any(tag => tag.TagId == searchTag)
var anyCall = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Enumerable), nameof(Enumerable.Any), new[] { typeof(Tag) },
    Expression.Property(taggable, "Tags"), Expression.Lambda(anyCondition, tag));
// searchTags.All(searchTag => taggable.Tags.Any(tag => tag.TagId == searchTag))
var allCall = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Enumerable), nameof(Enumerable.All), new[] { typeof(long) },
    Expression.Constant(searchTags), Expression.Lambda(anyCall, searchTag));
// taggable => searchTags.All(searchTag => taggable.Tags.Any(tag => tag.TagId == searchTag))
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(allCall, taggable);
```