How to create dynamic generic where clause for Entity Framework? I tried but does not work with ICollection or Collection properties
I am trying to create a dynamic Where clause so that where clause generate on run time as par parameters. I written code working fine with direct object but when every try to pass properties from Collect it throws this error:

System.ArgumentException: 'Instance property 'Name' is not defined for type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[Child]' (Parameter 'propertyName')'

Complete code is shown here:
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Child Child { get; set; }   // This worked
    public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; } // This collection does not work.
}

// Sample child entity
public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}

And I am using above code as follows:
public static void Main()
{
    using (var context = new MyDbContext())
    {
        // Example of filtering by parent entity and its collection of child entities.
        var filters = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    { "Name", "Parent1" },
                    { "Child.Name","Child2" }  //Worked
                    { "Children.Name", "Child1" } // Not work
                };
        
        var results = ApplyDynamicWhereClause<Parent>(context.Parents, filters).Include(p => p.Children).ToList();
        
        foreach (var parent in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{parent.Name}:");

            foreach (var child in parent.Children)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"  {child.Name}");
            }
        }
    }
    
    public IQueryable<T> ApplyDynamicWhereClause<T>(IQueryable<T> query, Dictionary<string, object> filters)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    
        Expression predicate = Expression.Constant(true); 
    
        foreach (var filter in filters)
        {
            string[] propertyPath = filter.Key.Split('.');
    
            Expression property = parameter;
            Type currentType = typeof(T);
    
            foreach (var propertyName in propertyPath)
            {
                property = Expression.Property(property, propertyName);
                currentType = currentType.GetProperty(propertyName).PropertyType;
            }
    
            var constant = Expression.Constant(filter.Value);
            var equals = Expression.Equal(property, constant);
    
            predicate = Expression.AndAlso(predicate, equals);
        }
    
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(predicate, parameter);
        return query.Where(lambda);
    }
}

And mock DbContext is:
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Child> Children { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        //optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase("TestDb");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Seed some data for testing
        modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>().HasData(
            new Parent { Id = 1, Name = "Parent1" },
            new Parent { Id = 2, Name = "Parent2" });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Child>().HasData(
            new Child { Id = 1, Name = "Child1", ParentId = 1 },
            new Child { Id = 2, Name = "Child2", ParentId = 1 },
            new Child { Id = 3, Name = "Child3", ParentId = 2 });
    }
}

I tried everything from the Google, but nothing worked.

Where is the code that used the above code?

@Fildor I added complete code for better understanding

Check this my answer. Let me know if you still have questions.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv Seems interesting will come to you after deep study of your code.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv  I checked your code there me be performance concern according my knowledge because you are using Recursive function and a lot code. But my code only working with few lines only only issue is Collection is not working

Peformance issues??? You really think it is problem for such function, OMG. EF Core has a tons of recursive code, do not use it. Your code is not working because it needs recursion or at least stack.

The real performance issues come from inefficient SQL and missing indexes, not inefficient SQL generators. Although a SQL generator that splits filter strings will cause needless garbage collections due to all those temporary strings. Searching for the same properties over and over is wasteful too. You could at least create a dictionary that maps names to PropertyInfo objects. The equivalent of AndAlso is a simple if (useFilter){ query=query.Where(extraCondition);.

You should probably check LINQKit and either use it directly or check how it works.

@PanagiotisKanavos, it is more complex task, function from { "Children.Name", "Child1" }, should generate query = query.Where(x => x.Children.Any(c => c.Name == "Child1")).

@SvyatoslavDanyliv Are you sure you want to reinvent OData or Graphql?

@JonasHøgh, how this simple filter is related to these two monsters?

What you want is basically to use Any from Enumerable, you could check if the property implements IEnumerable and then do an expression call like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15368230/162699

it is more complex task in that case the question should be edited to show the real problem.

And yes, OData and GraphQL are related as the question seems to be trying to parse a custom query string and apply it to LINQ. It's worth checking how libraries like HotChocolate (for GraphQL) and ASP.NET Core OData (for OData) do this. The ODataQueryOptions class can apply an OData request over any IQueryable with ApplyTo.

Both libraries are open source and the code is available on Github. QueryDataOptions passes filtering to FilterQueryOptions. The important part is parsing the query into useful intermediate types that are easier to map and apply to an IQueryable. Filtering all child entities by a property is a very different thing from filtering by a single child property

@SvyatoslavDanyliv I modified your code and working fine right now .. Thanks man

This is credit to @SvyatoslavDanyliv . Thanks man.
Complete code link of @SvyatoslavDanyliv  which I changed and only changed code is posted in the answer How to select many from string in efcore?
I modified your code only tow functions and it is achieved my target. Now I can post as much as possible condition from frontend. Following are the code which I modified and rest of the function is the same.
I want to return Expression instead of Querable return, want to add it into repository and can be used into my injected Services as parameters that can work along with other parameters.
Now working fine and thanks once again @SvyatoslavDanyliv  your code helped me a lot. I am using Recursive function instead due to lack of time will continue to improve it to improve its performance.
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Where<T>(DbContext context, IList<qCondition.whereClause> filters)
 {
     IQueryable<T> returnResult = null;
     var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");
     Expression expression = Expression.Constant(true);
     foreach (var key in filters)
     {
         if (key.condition == "()")
         {
             var dynamicQuery = FilterQuery(context.Model, parameter, key.field, propExpression =>
                 Expression.Call(EnsureString(propExpression), nameof(string.Contains), Type.EmptyTypes,
             Expression.Constant(key.value)));

             expression = Expression.AndAlso(expression, dynamicQuery);
         }
         else if (key.condition == "*=")
         {
             var dynamicQuery = FilterQuery(context.Model, parameter, key.field, propExpression =>
                 Expression.Call(EnsureString(propExpression), nameof(string.StartsWith), Type.EmptyTypes,
             Expression.Constant(key.value)));

             expression = Expression.AndAlso(expression, dynamicQuery);
         }
          else if (key.condition == "=*")
         {
             var dynamicQuery = FilterQuery(context.Model, parameter, key.field, propExpression =>
                 Expression.Call(EnsureString(propExpression), nameof(string.EndsWith), Type.EmptyTypes,
             Expression.Constant(key.value)));

             expression = Expression.AndAlso(expression, dynamicQuery);
         }
         else
         {
             var dynamicQuery = FilterQuery(context.Model, parameter,key.field, propExpression =>
             {
                 if (key.value == null)
                 {
                     var propType = propExpression.Type;
                     if (propType.IsValueType)
                     {
                         propExpression = Expression.Convert(propExpression, typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(propType));
                     }
                 }
                 if(key.condition=="=")
                     return Expression.Equal(propExpression, Expression.Constant(Convert.ChangeType(key.value, propExpression.Type), propExpression.Type));
                 else if(key.condition=="!=")
                     return Expression.NotEqual(propExpression, Expression.Constant(Convert.ChangeType(key.value, propExpression.Type), propExpression.Type));
                 else if(key.condition=="<")
                     return Expression.LessThan(propExpression, Expression.Constant(Convert.ChangeType(key.value, propExpression.Type), propExpression.Type));
                 else if(key.condition==">")
                     return Expression.GreaterThan(propExpression, Expression.Constant(Convert.ChangeType(key.value, propExpression.Type), propExpression.Type));
                 else if(key.condition=="<=")
                     return Expression.LessThanOrEqual(propExpression, Expression.Constant(Convert.ChangeType(key.value, propExpression.Type), propExpression.Type));
                  else 
                     return Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(propExpression, Expression.Constant(Convert.ChangeType(key.value, propExpression.Type), propExpression.Type));
             });
             expression = Expression.AndAlso(expression, dynamicQuery);
         }
     }

     var finalResult = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(expression, parameter);
     return finalResult;
     //return query.Where(finalResult);
 }

And another function which I eddited
private static Expression FilterQuery(IModel model, ParameterExpression exp, string propPath, Func<Expression, Expression> filterFactory)
{
    var propNames = propPath.Split('.');
    var parameter = exp;
    var filter = BuildFilter(exp, model, propNames, 0, filterFactory);
    // var filterLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(filter, entityParameter);
    // return query.Where(filterLambda);
    return filter;

}

Now I can pass as many as parameters with multiple conditions. Working with following input parameters
new List<parameters>
{
    new parameter{key:"Name",operator:"=", value : "abcd"},
    new parameter{key:"Students.Classes.Class.classTitle",operator:"()-Contains", value : "V"},
 new parameter{key:"Students.BasicInformation.FirstName",operator:"*=", value : "xyz"},
}

